# CSS Wildcard Rewrite

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using a PHP file manager add in for a tool here at work but they have the following CSS which is messing with the CSS i'm currently using:

```
* {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I tried changing it to this, which fixed my original stylesheet issues, but now the file manager displays incorrectly:

```
div[id^="fm"] {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

div[class^="fm"] {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Am I writing these incorrectly?  All of the styling they use starts with fm and ranges from both classes and ids.

Comment: how is it 'messing with the css [you're] currently using'?  what is it doing now?  what do you want it to do?

Comment: `border-box` is a common way of correcting the box model across multiple browsers when you aren't using a strict doc type.  Sounds like you should revisit your code to work with this box model instead of trying to break everything else.

Comment: I have a header section which it is basically removing the padding from the bottom of the header.  It's just visual look which bugs me and especially my boss.  I've tried readding that padding back as well as placing the !important on it, but it keeps getting overwritten by this * css section

Comment: Can you post some HTML? Maybe put it on jsfiddle.net as well? Judging from this limited data I think you could override the current CSS by increasing specificity, i.e. by adding parent elements in the CSS declaration.

Comment: can you show code in jsfiddel.net ?

Comment: Bah, sorry about this.  Of course as soon as I think i've hit a dead end and post it to SO I end up finding something...

So this is probably extremely rigged, but this is how I solved it.  I added the following to my #header css styling so that it would go back to the default:

    #header {
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }

Comment: FYI I'll add this as an answer but it says I can't until 7 hours have past lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed the file manager in a container `div`, give that div a class "foobar" and change your css to:

```
.foobar * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that's much better than what I did up above!  Thanks!